# How to make a handler call a function inside an object, in Google Apps Script (Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

When adding handlers to user interfaces in Google Apps you also provide the handler with a callback function, for example like this:

```js
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var handler = app.createServerHandler('myFunction');
```

I want the handler to call a method within an object, like so:

```js
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var handler = app.createServerHandler('myObject.myMethod');
```

But I always get the response "**Script function myObject.myMethod() could not be found**" when trying to run the script.

I've been searching in the GAS documentation and more or less all over the web for how to make this work, but so far no luck. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Unless things have changed, all vars are wiped out when the call back is called. I suspect they use "AppEngine" or something, as it feels like it sometimes it calls a different server.

**HTML Service:** is probably what you want https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Also, maybe you use the **tag** Google-Apps-Script ;)